# Yii2: update field Error Unknown column with query builder

Tags: mysql, pyyaml

**I have database table 'cat_ralation'**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat_relation` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`obj_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`obj_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**insert data**

```
id = 1,
cat_id = 2,
obj_id = 3,
obj_type = product
```

**Qyery builder**

```
Yii::$app->db
   ->createCommand()
   ->update('cat_relation',['cat_id'=>3], 'obj_id = 3 AND obj_type = product')
   ->execute();
```

**error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `cat_relation` SET `cat_id`=2 WHERE obj_id = 4 AND obj_type = product
```

Comment: I don't know nothing about pyyaml but shouldn't you quote `product` in quotes like `"product"` or `\'product\'`?

Comment: Where is the relation to PyYAML? I don't see any YAML in your examples. What is your actual question?

Comment: seems like your project is in yii2

Answer (score 0):

make it like

```
Yii::$app->db
   ->createCommand()
   ->update('cat_relation',['cat_id'=>3], "obj_id = 3 AND obj_type = 'product'")
   ->execute();
```